# Exact Target Create Subscriber issue (using SOAP API)

Tags: marketing-cloud

When I try to create a subscriber using SOAP API, I get this error:

Status Message: Access violation for account id (xxxxxxx). Error Code: 12020 Ordinal: 0

I also included the ChannelMemberID in the code. In the [link](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/error_codes/12000_12099_subscriber_object/), the error code 12020 is listed as

OYBAccessError
Can somebody explain what this means and how to resolve it?

Thank you.
Sai.

Answer (score 1):

Its kind of a weird issue.  I've asked around, and this happens when the ChannelMemberID set on a Subscriber and the MemberID it listed was not a child of the MemberID of the user making the API request.  So, I would double check that ChannelMemberID, and perhaps try leaving it blank.

Comment: Thanks Timothy. The issue happened to be in the way the attributes were being set. Found this out by eliminating the non-mandatory properties of the Subscriber object piece by piece. Also, removed the ChannelMemberID like you suggested, it was not required. All set now.